Cognito NameID Persistent to Unspecified
IHAC who is getting an unsatisfied nameid policy error. The issue is because the external authentication provider using saml requires the unspecified format for NameID but it seems Cognito only supports the Persistent format. Is there a workaround for this issue?
I was thinking of having the customer create a custom attribute, set that custom attribute to unspecified, put the nameID info in that attribute, then use that custom attribute instead of the nameID. However, the customer doesn't want to go down this path.

I'm having the same issue but for some reason it occurs only when the customer asks for Signing SAML requests and encrypting SAML assertions.
When the don't, the sp-initiated login works just fine.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
